# Flask isn't getting the checkbox value

Tags: python, checkbox, flask, request

I am trying to print off the checkbox value in Flask when I hit the submit button.

**app.py snippet:**

```
@app.route('/test2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test2():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit':
            print(request.args.get('check'))

    return render_template('test.html')
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"><br>
  <form role="form" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="test">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

It returns 'None' when I hit the submit button.

I have also tried request.form.get()

```
@app.route('/test2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test2():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit':
            print(request.form.get('check'))

    return render_template('test.html')
```

That also returns 'None'.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When submitting an HTML form, unchecked checkboxes do not send any data.  On Flask's side, there will not be a key in `form`, since no value was received.  If you want to check if a single checkbox (with a unique name) is checked, just test if it's name is in `form`.  If you want to check which of multiple checkboxes (with the same name, but different values) are checked, use `getlist` instead.

One boolean:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
```

```
checked = 'check' in request.form
```

Multiple options:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="3">
```

```
selected = request.form.getlist('check')
any_selected = bool(selected)
```